# Getting the first sub directory name from a URL

Tags: php, regex, string

I have been trying to get the first subdirectory of a URL using all kinds of string manipulation functions and have been having a lot of trouble. I was wondering if anyone knew of an easy way to accomplish this?

I appreciate any advice, thanks in advance!

```
http://www.domain.com/pages/images/apple.png //output: pages

www.domain.com/pages/b/c/images/car.png // output: pages

domain.com/one/apple.png // output: one
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use php function [parse_url()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php);

```
$url = 'domain.com/one/apple.png';
$path = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);

$firstSubDir = explode('/', $path)[1]; // [0] is the domain [1] is the first subdirectory, etc.
echo $firstSubDir; //one
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This does not work. It echoes `domain.com`.

Comment: You need to change `$firstSubDir = explode('/', $path)[0];` to `$firstSubDir = explode('/', $path)[1];` then it works :)

Comment: Method is sound but the syntax is a little off. `$firstSubDir = explode('/', $path)[1];`

Answer (score 0):

```
function startsWith($haystack, $needle)
{
    return $needle === "" || strpos($haystack, $needle) === 0;
}

$url = "http://www.domain.com/pages/images/apple.png";

$urlArr = explode('/', $url);

echo (startsWith($url, 'http')) ? $urlArr[3] : $urlArr[1]; // Should echo 'pages'
```

The above should work on both with and without 'http' as url-prefix case.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative function to get first path from URL (with or without `scheme`).

```
function domainpath($url = '')
{
    $url        = preg_match("@^https?://@", $url) ? $url : 'http://' . $url;
    $url        = parse_url($url);
    $explode    = explode('/', $url['path']);

    return $explode[1];
}

echo domainpath('http://www.domain.com/pages/images/apple.png');
echo domainpath('https://domain.com/pages/images/apple.png');
echo domainpath('www.domain.com/pages/b/c/images/car.png');
echo domainpath('domain.com/one/apple.png');
```